# AngularJS - How to structure a custom filter with ng-repeat to return items conditionally

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I have an ng-repeat that prints list items. I want to write a custom filter so that the list item will print, only if a condition is true.

I seem to have the structure wrong as it seems the variables are not getting passed through to the filter.

**index.php**

```
<div ng-show="userDetails.username" class="nav">
    <p>Menu</p>
    <li ng-repeat="menuItem in menu | matchAccessLevel:$rootScope.userDetails.accessLevel:menuItem.minAccess | orderBy:'position' ">
        <a ng-href="/angular-app/app/{{menuItem.id}}">{{menuItem.name}}</a>
    </li>
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
userApp.filter('matchAccessLevel', function() {
    return function( item, userAccessLevel, minAccessLevel ) {
        if( userAccessLevel >= minAccessLevel ) {
            return item;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Filters don't work on individual items in the array, they transform the entire array into another array.

```
userApp.filter('matchAccessLevel', function() {
  return function( items, userAccessLevel) {
    var filtered = [];
    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
      if(userAccessLevel >= item.minAccess) {
        filtered.push(item);
      }
    });
    return filtered;
  };
});
```

See this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/nuSlCRB6Y7QbuLC67uzW?p=preview)

**always inspect the arguments to a function. It's not always obvious what the values are.*

see [filters guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter)

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation. It seems I understood how filters work incorrectly. That's made it much clearer.

Comment: what i got not right was the argument thing. is there any documentation about how filter provide arguments/parameters ?

Comment: always inspect the arguments to a function. It's not always obvious what the values are

Comment: Is it possible we make accessLevel dynamic i.e. depending on a text box value? instead of getting it from scope?

Comment: @ons-jjss you can two way bind the scope value to ng-model on the desired input

Comment: Ok. I tried to set this from a text box scope variable but filter was not showing correct results when entering different value in the text box.

Comment: @ons-jjss http://plnkr.co/edit/nuSlCRB6Y7QbuLC67uzW?p=preview remember that you might be overwriting primitive values in child scopes see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/17607794/527968

Comment: Ok. It is fixed now. Thanks.

Comment: If I add track by in the ng-repeat. It throw error with this solution. Why?

Comment: @HughHou please ask a new question as this is not related to this question

Answer (score 6):

You can use Array.filter for a more concise solution:

```
app.filter('matchAccessLevel', function() {
    return function( items, userAccessLevel ) {
      return items.filter(function(element){
        return userAccessLevel >= element.minAccess;
      });
    }
});
```

[Check on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8sjtMvXvv3i5wy07oG7s?p=preview)

Answer (score -1):

For CoffeeScript lovers:

```
userApp.filter 'matchAccessLevel', ->
  (items, userAccessLevel) ->
    item for item in items when userAccessLevel >= item.minAccess
```