# Using filters in angularjs with hardcoded checkboxes

Tags: angularjs, filtering

I have a checkbox list that I would like to use to filter a list. the checkbox list is hard codes and looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="characteristics.nontraditional" ng-true-value="non-tradtional" ng-false-value="">&#160; Non Traditional<br>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="characteristics.metal" ng-true-value="metal" ng-false-value="">&#160; Metal<br>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="characteristics.plancha" ng-true-value="plancha" ng-false-value="">&#160; Plancha<br>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="characteristics.rocket" ng-true-value="rocket" ng-false-value="">&#160; Rocket<br>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="characteristics.wick" ng-true-value="wick" ng-false-value="">&#160; Wick
```

I have my ng-repeat looking like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="stove in stoves | filteredstoves:characteristics">
```

and my custom filter looking like this:

```
stovecat.filter('filteredstoves', function() {
  return function(stoves, characteristics) { 
    alert(characteristics)
         }
    } 
}
```

When I load the page. The alert contains "undefined" which is expected as no checkbox has been selected. When I select one or more checkboxes, the alert contains [Object object], which is fine as an object is now passed into the custom filter. How do I access these values passed into my custom filter so that I can filter the list accordingly? Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks folks!

Comment: which values you want to access ??

Comment: [Answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15197233/2013981).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plunker with solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/7PhNEADHW099w9kaqS7M?p=preview

template:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="characteristics.nontraditional">&#160; Non Traditional</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="characteristics.metal">&#160; Metal</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="characteristics.plancha">&#160; Plancha</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="characteristics.rocket">&#160; Rocket</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="characteristics.wick">&#160; Wick</input><br/>

<div ng-repeat="stove in stoves | filteredstoves:characteristics">{{stove.name}} - {{stove.characteristics}}</div>
```

filter:

```
stovecat.filter('filteredstoves', function() {
  return function(stoves, characteristics) {
    var result = stoves.slice(); // copy array
    angular.forEach(characteristics, function(value, key) {
      if(value) {
        for(var index = 0; index < result.length; index++) {
          stove = result[index];
          if(stove.characteristics.indexOf(key) == -1) {
            result.splice(index--,1);
          }
        }
      }
    });
    return result;
  }
});
```

Just go through all characteristics in filter and remove the items without them