# Angular ng-repeat with array length condition

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want the `ng-repeat` to *run* only when the `photos.length > 1`

Doing this doesn't seem to work:

`<div ng-repeat="thumb in photos | photos.length > 1">`

Is there any quick trick / elegant way to do this? I just need to check for array length and nothing else fancy.

I would hate to duplicate the array to another array by doing something like this

```
if (oldArray.length > 1)
 newArray = photos;
else
 newArray = [];
```

...and then do `ng-repeat` on `newArray`. This seems inefficient.

Thanks.

Comment: Try creating your own filter. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196161/angularjs-how-to-structure-a-custom-filter-with-ng-repeat-to-return-items-cond

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try:

```
<div ng-repeat="thumb in photos" ng-if="photos.length > 1"></div>
```

if the `ng-if` condition is not satisfied those elements will be removed from the DOM. See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf for further reference.

Comment: It may also be helpful to check for the existence of 'photos' prior to accessing the length property since 'undefined' would not have a length property. For example: ng-if="photos && photos.length > 1"

Comment: how to have two if confition, before and after ng-repeat? for example, photos can be array or an error, if the type is string it's an error, and i have to check it before ng-repeat, but then i want to put condition on thumb, say if it meet specific condition, then i have to run it after ng-repeat...

Answer (score 5):

You could try using the ng -if directive to check the condition you describe e.g.

```
<div ng-if='photos.length > 1'> your HTML here </div>
```