# How can I access ngRepeat iterator scope from filter filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm writing some application that is a bit like e-shop. I have a list of entities and checkboxes to filter them. And I want to make that checkbox-filters be some sort of universal. I plan to write an expression in checkbox's attribute and then eval in within the scope of each entity by using filter filter in ngRepeat. The problem is how to access the scope of an entity from that filtering function. For example:

*My data (JS):*

```
food = [
  {
    category: 'fruits',
    name: 'Apple'
  },
  {
    category: 'vegetables',
    name: 'Potato'
  }
]
```

*My filter checkbox (HTML):*

```
<label>
  Fruits:
  <input type="checkbox" data-filter="category == 'fruits'" />
<label/>
```

*My list (HTML):*

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in food | filter:customFilterFunction">
  </li>
</ul>
```

*My filter function (JS):*

```
$scope.customFilterFunction = function(item) {
  // here I want to eval that expression written in checkbox's attribute
  // within the scope of each item in food array.
  // The problem is not how to access that expression,
  // but how to access the scope of item in food array.
}
```

Of course, I can create new scope from $rootScope each time I apply that filter function, and then pass all item properties to that new scope, and then eval that expression in this scope. But I think it would consume a lot of memory because of creating a lot of new scopes each time user changes the filters.

Do you know a better solution?

Comment: As far as i know `customFilterFunction` takes an array of items not individual item. See this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196161/angularjs-how-to-structure-a-custom-filter-with-ng-repeat-to-return-items-cond

Comment: Yes, filter is being applied to collection, not item. Thank you for reminder :)

Answer (score 0):

What's about following, without cusrtom filter?

```
Fruits & Apple:
<input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="fil" data-ng-true-value="{{category = 'fruits';name = 'Apple'}}" data-ng-false-value="" />
Fruits:
<input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="fil.category" data-ng-true-value="fruits" data-ng-false-value="" />
Vegetables:
<input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="fil.category" data-ng-true-value="vegetables" data-ng-false-value="" />

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in food | filter:fil">{{ item.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

**See in action:** [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/rnELG2NfHtcrS92MHrlZ?p=preview)

Comment: What if expression in one checkbox uses more that one condition: "category == 'fruits' && subcategory == 'citrus'"?

Comment: And what if i want to check more than one checkbox to filter all fruits and all vegetables?

Comment: see update :o) i make it with name, but subcategory should works similar. (edit: there is some bug with selecting, but you got the idea :))

Comment: One of possible solutions, but i'd rather prefer creating new scope each time the function executes. Or (as i've done already) pass object hashes to filter attributes and then compare that object with array items :)