# Get index of current filtered element in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've a custom function used as a filter. How can I get the index of the current element filtered.

```
<tr ng-repeat="(idx, line) in items | filter:inRange">....</tr>

//this is the filter
$scope.inRange = function(item) {
    //how to get the index here?
};
```

Please note that I do not want to use indexOf

```
var idx = $scope.items.indexOf(item);
```

Comment: `I do not want to use indexOf` It is not clear what you are expecting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in [another answer on SO with the same kind of issue on filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196161/angularjs-how-to-structure-a-custom-filter-with-ng-repeat-to-return-items-cond)

> Filters don't work on individual items in the array, they transform the entire array into another array.

When defined as filter, `inRange` will receive the whole `items` array, not single items.

```
myModule.filter('inRange', function() {
    return function(items) {
        var filtered = [];
        angular.forEach(items, function(item, index) {
            // do whatever you want here with the index
            filtered.push(item);
        });
        return filtered;
    }
});
```

Comment: yes, what you said true for a filter operating on the array.