# how to use custom filter in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

`In my code iam using custom filter for filtering gender(male,female).
but in my output when i click male it does not filter,but when i click female it shows filtered output consisting of only females. I dont know where is my mistake.

```
app.filter('myFilter', function () {
    return function (items, filterby) {
        var filtered    = [];
        var filtermatch = new RegExp(filterby, 'i');

        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

            if (filtermatch.test(items[i].gender) {
                filtered.push(items[i]);
            }
         }

         return filtered;
    };
});

<ul id="result">
    <li ng-repeat="x in details | myFilter:filterby">
        <div>Name:    {{x.name   }}</div>
        <div>Address: {{x.address}}</div>
        <div>Gender:  {{x.gender }}</div>
        <div>Country: {{x.country}}</div>
        <div>Agree:   {{x.agree  }}</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And this is my code for radio buttons male and female

```
<div class="form-group">

<label for="filterby" class="control-label col-xs-2">Filter By Gender</label>
    <div class="radio">

        <label>

            <input type="radio" name="options" id="options2" 
            ng-model="filterby" value="female">
            <label for="gender" class="control-label col-xs-2">Female</label>
        </label>

        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="options2" 
            ng-model="filterby" value="male">
            <label for="gender" class="control-label col-xs-2">male</label>
        </label>
    </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: so the syntax is wrong?

Comment: This answer may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196161/angularjs-how-to-structure-a-custom-filter-with-ng-repeat-to-return-items-cond

Comment: @RahilWazir: Why do you say the filter declaration is wrong ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem Because this http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25202584/1 is not correct way to create filters.

Comment: @RahilWazir: I see :)

Comment: but now i have corrected the syntax but still i have got that same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the fact that you are not using the `sort` argument, if you want to pass multiple parameters to a filter you separate them with `:`.

```
ng-repeat="x in details | myFilter:prop1:prop2">
```

This will call `myFilter(details, prop1, prop2)` and `ngRepeat` over the returned array.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably filtering correctly. The problem is the search term "male" will include both "female" and "male" because you can find the term "male" in fe**male**. Just use not female instead (i.e. !female).