# AngularJS, a component using custom filter

Tags: angularjs

So I have read this: [how to use custom filter in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25202584/how-to-use-custom-filter-in-angularjs) which has got me this far. and I didn't want to re-open as it is 3 years old.

the problem I am getting is this, this is copied from the chrome debugger in elements view, it has commented out my loop and filter so nothing has happened on screen.

```
<!-- ngRepeat: person in $ctrl.people |  icfilter:W -->
```

My app and filter

```
var app=angular.module("componentApp", []);

app.filter('icfilter', function() {
    return function(people, filterBy) {
        var out = [],
         lowerFilter = filterBy.toLowerCase();

        angular.forEach(people, function(person) {

          if (person.name.toLowerCase().includes( lowerFilter)){
              out.push(person);
          }
        });

        return out;

      }
});
```

the html template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app/component.js"></script>

<script src="app/namesList.component.js"></script>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">

<title>Components</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div ng-app="componentApp">
        <names-list></names-list>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and lastly my component

```
angular.module("componentApp").component("namesList",{
    template: '<div >' +
            '<h4>Family members:</h4>'+


            '<li ng-repeat="person in $ctrl.people |  icfilter:W">{{ person.name +", " + person.age }}</li>'+
        '</div>',
    controller: function namesListController(){
        this.filterBy="W";
        this.people = [ {
            age : 46,
            name : 'Wendy'
        }, {
            age : 50,
            name : 'Joe'
        }, {
            age : 11,
            name : 'Frank'
        }, {
            age : 6,
            name : 'Jenny'
        } ];
        this.sort='name';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost right. Make below changes and it should work:

```
'<li ng-repeat="person in $ctrl.people |  icfilter:\'W\'">
```

*You just missed single quotes when passing `W`* :)

Here is [the plunker for reference](https://plnkr.co/edit/YPn9lZOX1vlalgjinwXK?p=preview)

Comment: Ahh thanks, that makes sense. Which would explain why after all the changes I made during my explorations and then when rebuilding and replacing W with $ctrl.filterBy it started working again.

Answer (score 1):

IT IS WORKING NOW, BUT I DON'T KNOW WHY.

I put it back together, replacing the code I had removed to make the answer smaller (sorts and filter boxes etc.) well it is working now.