# Filter within ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an object:

```
$scope.fields = {

    id:                     'uid',
    email:                  'mail',
    houseNumber:            'det.1',
    streetOne:              'det.2',
    streetTwo:              'det.3',
    county:                 'det.4',
    postcode:               'det.5',
    daytimeNumber:          'det.6',
    firstName:              'det.7',
    lastName:               'det.8',         
    fullName:               ['firstName', 'lastName'],
    address:                ['houseNumber', 'streetOne', 'streetTwo', 'county', 'postcode'],
    mobile:                 'det.9',
    subscribed:             'det.10',
    yearOfBirth:            'det.19',       
    model:                  'model',            
    serial:                 'serial',
    purchaseDate:           'purchase_date',
    registrationDate:       'registraition_date'

};
```

and an array:

```
$scope.chosenFields = ['id', 'email', 'fullName', 'postcode', 'subscribed', 'address'];
```

In my HTML I want to show the Keys from $scope.fields (e.g. model, serial, purchaseDate) that are not in $scope.chosenFields array. So I do this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in fields | filter:{checkFields:true}">{{key}}</li>
</ul>
```

And inside my checkFields filter, I don't get a call at all. Would this be a correct way of doing it at all?

Comment: `checkFields` is your custom filter then you should use `<li ng-repeat="(key, value) in fields | checkFields:true}">{{key}}</li>` true will passed to filter

Comment: That gives me an error: Unknown provider. Looks like it doesn't like passing custom filter to ng-repeat.

Comment: @Bravi no, that simply means you forgot to declare the filter, or to add the JS file as a script in the HTML, or to add the dependency tothe module.

Comment: @JBNizet ah yes, thanks - I misspelled the name. It doesn't show any errors anymore, however it doesn't work either. I created a filter that receives 1 argument and I just log out that argument and for some reason, only 4 console logs I can see AND the data output doesn't show anymore. Oh god, this is so complicated :))

Answer (score 0):

If `checkFields` is a filter, the way to call it is

```
... | checkFields:true
```

Your current code calls the angular filter `filter`, and passes it as argument the following object

```
{
    checkFields: true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution based on this:
[AngularJS - How to structure a custom filter with ng-repeat to return items conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196161/angularjs-how-to-structure-a-custom-filter-with-ng-repeat-to-return-items-cond)

```
app.filter('checkFields', function(){
   return function(fields, globalFields){
       var filtered = [];
       angular.forEach(fields, function(element, index){
           if(globalFields.indexOf(index)<0){
              filtered.push(index);
           }
       });
      return filtered;
   }
});
```