# Remove perticular entry from the ng-repeat while loading

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to remove some specific loop or entry from the list while is outputting. This is how my list looks like:

[image]

And i want to remove some particulate items from the list like: "Check it Our Archives", "Featured Profile". So how can this be possible? Is there any kind of filters i can use?

Here is how my `ng-repeat` is:

```
<ons-list-item modifier="chevron" class="list-item-container" ng-repeat="ListingData in AllData">
    <ons-row ng-click="setCurrentCategory(ListingData.slug);  app.navi.pushPage('directory-page.html', { animation : 'slide' } )">
        <ons-col>
            <div class="name">
              {{ListingData.title}}
            </div>
         </ons-col>
         <ons-col width="40px"></ons-col>
    </ons-row>
</ons-list-item>
```

If needed i can post the controller too.

Comment: Yes, looks like you could achieve this with a filter? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196161/angularjs-how-to-structure-a-custom-filter-with-ng-repeat-to-return-items-cond

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ng-if

```
 <div ng-if="ListingData.title !=  'Check it Our Archives' && ListingData.title !=  'Featured Profile'" class="name">
      {{ListingData.title}}
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your controller, before you pass the data to the view you could filter the items using `Array.prototype.filter`. Otherwise you can use the angular filters but it feels to me that if you don't want items to display, it shouldn't be passed to the view.

Below is a quick example of how the data in the scope can have the filtered contents of the array:

```
var pages =  [{ title : 'Page one'}, { title : 'Page two'}];

// this filters the pages array to display every item that is not titled "Page one"
$scope.data = pages.filter(function(p){
   return p.title !== 'Page one';
});
```

Comment: Can you please suggest me any example on the same?

Comment: Your answer is great! and it can work great! But the system i am using is not gonna be helpful for me. But it looks good to me.