# filter function ng-repeat returning true but 0 results are displayed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a custom function that returns true or false

controller function:

```
    this.isStoreEquipment = function(equipment){
        var returnVal = false
        if (Array.isArray(equipment)){
            equipment.forEach(function(piece, index, array){
                if (Config.myEquipment().indexOf(piece)!= -1){
                    returnVal = true
                    return
                }
            });             
        }
        return returnVal
    }
```

and in my table

```
        <tr ng-cloak id="{{$index}}"
            ng-repeat-start="equipment in currentController.storeEquipment | orderBy: '-lastService ' | filter: currentController.isStoreEquipment(equipment.storeNum))>"
            <td>{{equipment.lastService | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</td>
            <td>{{equipment.type}}</td>
            <td>{{equipment.name}}</td>
            <td>{{equipment.storeNum}}</td>
        </tr>
```

Now I have validated that this does return true by adding a `<td>currentController.isStoreEquipment(equipment.storeNum)` to my table and it is returning true and false like it should, HOWEVER i am not getting any results with the filter applied to my ng-repeat expression.

Comment: I dont' see any `ng-repeat-end` attribute, therefore don't use `ng-repeat-start`, but use `ng-repeat`.

Comment: @alesc The ng-repeat-end is futher on down the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should register filters like this:

```
 angular.module('test').filter('inStore', function() {
  return function(input) {
    ....
  }
});
```

They're usually more general functions, usable in more than one controller. That said, the `input` is the value on which you're applying the filter. In this case it's an array and the filter should return a new array with only the 'good' items.

Here's a nice example https://stackoverflow.com/a/15197233/3927379