# No data when typing using bootstrap and angularJS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I am using **typeahead** to display all my **cameraid** and to search my data too but it does not giving me any data on the **typeahead** as it is showing me `[object Object]`.

Anybody can help me with this?

[image]

**my html file:**

```
 <div class="container-fluid">

 <h1><a href="http://localhost:8081/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home
">Image Viewer</span></a></h1>
</div>
<br>
<div ng-controller="Hello" class="col-xs-12">


<b>Search:</b><br>

 <input type="text" ng-model="searchBox" uib-typeahead="state for state in records | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">        

 <table class="table table-striped table-hover" style="width:55%">
    <thead>
      <tr>

        <th>CamID</th>
        <th>Timestamp</th>
        <th>View Image</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="record in records | filter:searchBox | orderBy:'+timestamp'">

        <td>{{record.cameraid}}</td>
        <td>{{record.timestamp}}</td>
         <td>{{record.filename}}</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="toggleCustom()" onclick="myFunction()">View</button></td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

**My jsp file:**

```
var camListApp = angular.module('camListApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])
camListApp.controller("Hello", ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http){

$scope.custom = true;
$scope.toggleCustom = function() {
   $scope.custom = ! $scope.custom;
};

$http.get('http://localhost:8081/camera/list').then(function(response) {
     console.log(response);
        $scope.records= response.data; 
    });
}]);
```

**My json data:**

```
 [{"id":23,"cameraid":"001","timestamp":"2016/06/15 17:27","filename":"452c5d867b563e937d44d48ebc326c7a"},
{"id":24,"cameraid":"000000006f4280af","timestamp":"2016/06/15 17:27","filename":"ee90428e4e0c19ba9858285398bf4fbb"},
{"id":25,"cameraid":"002","timestamp":"2016/06/15 17:28","filename":"c9a4fb339f6981ffd679937724167de8"},
{"id":26,"cameraid":"000000006f4280af","timestamp":"2016/06/15 17:28","filename":"a1df86417d958e670750cf8172a2b7dd"}
```

Comment: i think you need to make custom filter check this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196161/angularjs-how-to-structure-a-custom-filter-with-ng-repeat-to-return-items-cond](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196161/angularjs-how-to-structure-a-custom-filter-with-ng-repeat-to-return-items-cond)

Comment: I able to filter my search but is the typeahead does not show me any of my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are returning all the objects that's why you get "object Object", you need to specify which part you gonna use.

`uib-typeahead="state.cameraid as state.cameraid for state in records | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8"`

The first state.cameraid is what you display in the list the second is the value.