# Custom filter angular on ng-repeat for stike text if disabled

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to add a custom filter on my angularJS app. I want di strike text like <del>this way</del> if the object in the ng-repat has the isDeleted flag set as true.
 Code: here the HTML:

```
<table id="tableText" class="table table-hover table-striped" ng-init="allNews()">
                <tr>
                    <th>Titolo</th>
                    <th>Text</th>
                    <th>Disattivato</th>
                    <th>Modifica</th>
                    <th ng-if="!cancelDelete">Elimina</th>
                    <th ng-if="cancelDelete">Annulla</th>
                </tr>

                <tr ng-repeat="news in allNews | filter: deleteTitleText(news)">
                    <td>
                        <div ng-hide="editingData[news.id]">{{ news.title }}</div>
                        <div ng-show="editingData[news.id]"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="news.title" /></div>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <div ng-hide="editingData[news.id]">{{ news.arg }}</div>
                        <div ng-show="editingData[news.id]"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="news.arg" /></div>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <div ng-hide="editingData[news.id]"><input type="checkbox" disabled ng-model="news.isDeleted"></div>
                        <div ng-show="editingData[news.id]"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="news.isDeleted"></div>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <div ng-hide="editingData[news.id]"><button id="modify" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="modify(news, $event)">Modifica</button></div>
                        <div ng-show="editingData[news.id]"><button id="accept" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="update(news)">Accetta</button></div>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <div ng-hide="editingData[news.id]"><button id="delete" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="delete(news.id)">Cancella</button></div>
                        <div ng-show="editingData[news.id]"><button id="cancel" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="cancelModify()">Annulla</button></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

The JS:

```
app.filter('deleteTitleText', function () {
return function (news) {
    if (news.isDeleted == true) {
        news.title = "<span><del>" + news.title + "</del></span>";
        news.arg = "<span><del>" + news.arg + "</del></span>";
    }
    return news;
}
});
```

This is a good way to implement this kind of filter? For now I receive this error: `angular.js:13920 Error: [filter:notarray] Expected array but received: function ()`. Thanks

Comment: why do you need a filter, `<div ng-hide="editingData[news.id]">{{ news.title }}</div>` replacing it to `<div ng-hide="editingData[news.id]"><span ng-hide="news.isDeleted">{{ news.title }}</span><span ng-show="news.isDeleted"><del>{{ news.title }}</del></span></div>` and removing filter should also work, or do you have any specific requirement to use filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OPTION 1:

```
<table id="tableText" class="table table-hover table-striped" ng-init="allNews()">
    <tr>
        <th>Titolo</th>
        <th>Text</th>
        <th>Disattivato</th>
        <th>Modifica</th>
        <th ng-if="!cancelDelete">Elimina</th>
        <th ng-if="cancelDelete">Annulla</th>
    </tr>

    <tr ng-repeat="news in allNews">
        <td>
            <div ng-hide="editingData[news.id]">
                <span ng-hide="news.isDeleted">{{ news.title }}</span>
                <span ng-show="news.isDeleted"><del>{{ news.title }}</del></span>
                <!-- USING ng-if -->
                <!--
                <span ng-if="!news.isDeleted">{{ news.title }}</span>
                <span ng-if="news.isDeleted"><del>{{ news.title }}</del></span>
                -->
            </div>
            <div ng-show="editingData[news.id]"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="news.title" /></div>
        </td>

        <td>
            <div ng-hide="editingData[news.id]">
                <span ng-hide="news.isDeleted">{{ news.arg }}</span>
                <span ng-show="news.isDeleted"><del>{{ news.arg }}</del></span>
                <!-- USING ng-if -->
                <!--
                <span ng-if="!news.isDeleted">{{ news.arg }}</span>
                <span ng-if="news.isDeleted"><del>{{ news.arg }}</del></span>
                -->
            </div>
            <div ng-show="editingData[news.id]"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="news.arg" /></div>
        </td>

        <td>
            <div ng-hide="editingData[news.id]"><input type="checkbox" disabled ng-model="news.isDeleted"></div>
            <div ng-show="editingData[news.id]"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="news.isDeleted"></div>
        </td>

        <td>
            <div ng-hide="editingData[news.id]"><button id="modify" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="modify(news, $event)">Modifica</button></div>
            <div ng-show="editingData[news.id]"><button id="accept" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="update(news)">Accetta</button></div>
        </td>

        <td>
            <div ng-hide="editingData[news.id]"><button id="delete" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="delete(news.id)">Cancella</button></div>
            <div ng-show="editingData[news.id]"><button id="cancel" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="cancelModify()">Annulla</button></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

OPTION 2:

```
<span ng-bind-html="news | deleteTitleText"></span>

app.filter('deleteTitleText', function ($sce) {
    return function (input) {
        if(input.isDeleted) {
            output = $sce.trustAsHtml("<del>"+input.title+"</del>");
        } else {
            output = $sce.trustAsHtml("<span>"+input.title+"</span>");
        }
        return output;
    };
});
```

remove filter from ng-repeat `<tr ng-repeat="news in allNews">`

So final would be similar to :

```
<tr ng-repeat="news in allNews">
    <td>
        <div ng-hide="editingData[news.id]">
            <span ng-bind-html="news | deleteTitleText"></span>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="editingData[news.id]"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="news.title" /></div>
    </td>
    ....
    ....
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I prefer use a filter: maybe before the release, someone prefer to change the style.

Comment: @MicheleBoscagin - please check option 2, i have just added a snippet, it needs some finishing as per requirement

Answer (score 1):

You need to alter you filter to expect the entire `allNews` array/object and work with that instead of just a single item in the list.

[This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196161/angularjs-how-to-structure-a-custom-filter-with-ng-repeat-to-return-items-cond).

For instance:

```
app.filter('deleteTitleText', function () {
    return function (allNews) {
        var filtered = [];
        angular.forEach(allNews, function(news) {
            if (news.isDeleted == true) {
                news.title = "<span><del>" + news.title + "</del></span>";
                news.arg = "<span><del>" + news.arg + "</del></span>";
            }
            filtered.push(news);
        });
        return filtered;
    }
});
```

Your ng-repeat should be changed from:

```
ng-repeat="news in allNews | filter: deleteTitleText(news)"
```

To:

```
ng-repeat="news in allNews | deleteTitleText"
```

Comment: Same error: `angular.js:13920 Error: [filter:notarray] Expected array but received: function ()` Something wrong in the html?

Comment: I think this will create a recursion for `news.title` and `news.arg`

Comment: Correct @Aks1357, just divide between `news.title` and `news.arg`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use ng-style, like in this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/0koMSQ54gUChdpB4Vrrm?p=preview

`!item.isDisabled ? {'text-decoration': 'line-through'} : {'text-decoration': 'none'}`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `ng-show` and `ng-hide`

```
<tr ng-repeat="news in allNews">
    <span ng-show="news.isDeleted"><del>{{news.title}}</del></span>
    <span ng-show="news.isDeleted"><del>{{news.arg}}</del></span>
    <span ng-hide="news.isDeleted"><del>{{news.title}}</del></span>
    <span ng-hide="news.isDeleted"><del>{{news.arg}}</del></span>
    .
    .
    .
</tr>
```

Comment: I prefer use a filter: maybe before the release, someone prefer to change the style.

Comment: I don't really understand the reason but ok sorry for not providing the right answer

Comment: Not a problem :) usefull for others!