# Weighted sorting of results from Angular's built-in filter

Tags: angularjs, sorting

What is the most efficient way to do a weighted sort of the results of Angular's built-in filter?

One of the first lessons we encounter when learning Angular is to filter an ng-repeat list based on the contents of a text box:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="textFilter" />
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="band in favoriteBands | filter:textFilter">
        {{ band.name }} ({{ band.singer }}, {{ band.guitar }}, {{ band.etc }})
    <li>
</ul>
```

In this case, entering "Hendrix" in the text box could match on Jimi Hendrix for the guitar field and on The Jimi Hendrix Experience for the band name.  In this case, I want all of the matches on band.name to sort to the top.  Matches on band.guitar should come next, but matches on both should go to the very top.

What's the best way to set up an `orderBy` to do this?  Should I write a function to inspect each field in each record to look for a match and assign a weighted relevance score?  That seems like I'm doing the filter work all over again, but I haven't found a better approach.  Are there better ways to do it?

**EDIT**: To clarify, this question is not about whether or not to show a result conditionally, but rather about sorting the items that do pass the filter.  I want to give fields in each object different weights.  Let's say band.name has a weight of 5, the band.guitarist has a weight of 2, and the other fields have a weight of 1.  If I search for "Tom Petty", I'd get a total of 8 for Tom Petty and the Heartbreakers - 5 for band.name, 1 for Tom Petty in band.singer, and 2 for Tom Petty in band.guitar.  For the Travelling Wilburies, I'd only get 3 (1 for band.singer and 2 for band.guitar).  I can then use those scores to determine the sorting.  There are any number of sorting algorithms you could use - this is just an example.

Comment: Did you used this "band in favoriteBands | filter:textFilter | orderBy:['name','guitar']"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS - How to structure a custom filter with ng-repeat to return items conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196161/angularjs-how-to-structure-a-custom-filter-with-ng-repeat-to-return-items-cond)

Comment: This isn't about conditionally showing items, it's about sorting them and determining their order in the list. It's using Angular's native filtering, not custom filtering.

Comment: Would orderBy:['name', 'guitar'] allow me to specify weights for each field? In the full version I'll have more than two fields to consider, and it won't be as simple as a primary, secondary, and tertiary sort.

Comment: There is a custom filtered answer in the link above, You can call the same filter like that. Inside of the function, you can write your conditions and then add them to a new list(means they will be already sorted) and return the list back.

Comment: @VolkanAkınPaşa - So, you're suggesting that I write a custom filter that handles the sorting based on whatever weights I want to use?  It then outputs a correctly sorted array?  That makes sense.  I still think this is a different question than the one you linked to as a possible duplicate.  If you care to, submit it as an answer and I can set it as correct one.